# Uncaught RangeError: Unsupported time zone specified undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Попытка в Хроме вызвать `toLocaleString` у даты на любой вкладке кроме `about:blank` падает с ошибкой

> ```
> Uncaught RangeError: Unsupported time zone specified undefined
>     at new DateTimeFormat (native)
>     at Date.toLocaleString (native)
>     at <anonymous>:3:15
> ```

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
console.log(d + "");
console.log(d.toLocaleString());
```

> Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
>   Revision    57c9d07b416b5a2ea23d28247300e4af36329bdc-refs/branch-heads/3163@{#1250}
>   OS  Windows
>   JavaScript  V8 6.1.534.41
>   Flash   27.0.0.130  C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_27_0_0_130.dll

OS Windows 10 x64 Ru (но Хром английский).

[image: скриншот]

И в сниппете:

[image: скриншот сниппета]

В Firefox всё работает:

[image: Скриншот из FF]

В чём проблема?

Comment: Наверное, можно было бы закрыть вопрос как невоспроизводящийся, но пока оставлю, вдруг кто-то ещё сталкивался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После перезагрузки компьютера всё заработало. Версия хрома при этом та же самая. Видимо, какой-то временный глюк - либо хрома, либо системы.

[image: Скриншот]

> Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
>   Revision    57c9d07b416b5a2ea23d28247300e4af36329bdc-refs/branch-heads/3163@{#1250}
>   OS  Windows
>   JavaScript  V8 6.1.534.41
>   Flash   27.0.0.130 C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_27_0_0_130.dll